# Do NOT remove spaces in a variable

Tags: sql, linux, bash, variables

I'm creating a variable in a bash script, to pull a field from an sql database. There might be spaces in there, and I want to see that.

```
SIDE_NBR=$($CMD_CONNX "select side_nbr from setup" | awk 'NR==6{print$1}'|tr -d '\r'
```

I need the tr -d '\r' as it comes in with a carriage return. However, this field might be

```
"    4"
```

or

```
"4"
```

I want to see those spaces so when i call my variable later, i can

```
log "Side_nbr=\"$SIDE_NBR\""
```

And in my log would display "    4" or "4"

Comment: That was my thought, but it's not coming across as such.

Comment: `{print $1}` will remove all leading spaces with the default delimiter.

Comment: The problem is that `awk` uses spaces to split the line into fields.

Comment: just do `awk 'NR==6'` instead.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're only printing $1 instead of the whole line?

Comment: BTW, you can use awk's `sub()` function to remove the `\r`

Comment: A few people said it the answer. i didn't know {print$1} removes leading spaces. Just doing NR==6 fixed my issue. Thank you every one!

Answer (score 0):

To have an official answer posted.

{print$1} in awk will remove leading spaces.

Just using 'NR==6' works for what i'm doing. Thanks every one!

Comment: It's not the `print` that removes the spaces. By default, *all* whitespace is treated as the field delimiter; the whitespace is removed as soon as `awk` splits the current line into fields.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a bit more than you need for this one particular case, but something that may come in handy down the road if you plan on pulling SQL query results into your shell script ...

Consider wrapping the (database) field value in a pair of delimiters that do not show up in the field; examples could include a pipe (`|`), period (`.`), or even a multi-character delimiter that increases the chance of not finding a match in the (database) field (eg, `.|.`).

You can then have `awk` use the same delimiter for splitting fields.

You can go a bit further and flag just the data row for selection by providing a field to grep/pattern-match on (eg, the string 'GREPME').  This eliminates the need to know in advance the line number(s) that contain your data.

Let's start with the SQL query and we'll use a pipe (`|`) as our delimiter:

```
$CMD_CONNX "select 'GREP'||'ME','|'||side_nbr||'|' from setup"
```

**NOTE**: To keep from matching a column header of 'GREPME' we need to split the string into 2 parts thus ensuring only the data row contains the string 'GREPME'.

**NOTE**: Depending on the RDBMS and column datatype it may be necessary to convert the column to a (var)char before appending the delimiter on the front/back of the column.

Let's assume your complete output looks something like:

```
Connecting to database xyz ...
Connect as myuser/***** ...

GREP||ME    |||side_nbr|||
=========== ==================
GREPME      |   4|
(1 row affected)
```

One `awk` solution to parse out the desired data:

```
awk -F"|" '/GREPME/ {print $2}'
```

Pulling it all together:

```
SIDE_NBR=$($CMD_CONNX "select 'GREP'||'ME','|'||side_nbr||'|' from setup" | awk -F"|" '/GREPME/ {print $2}')
```

---

It gets a bit more interesting if your SQL query tool provides a non-white-space column delimiter for the result set (eg, a pipe (`|`)):

```
|Column1|Column2      |
|=======|=============|
|ABC    |some data    | 
|DEF    |and more data|
```

Parsing this output has issues because of the 'extra' white space for the first column due to the column header being wider than the data, and for the first row/second column due to the second row/second column value being wider.

There are several ways to get around this ... one example using an ampersand (`&`) as the delimiter:

```
select 'GREP'||'ME&'||Column1||'&'||Column2||'&' from mytable

|GREP||ME&||Column1||&||Column2||&|
|=================================|
|GREPME&ABC&some data&            |
|GREPME&DEF&and more data&        |
```

Which could be parsed with `awk` like such:

```
<select_query> ... | awk -F"&" '/GREPME/ {print $2,$3)' | while read -r col1 col2; do ...
```

Anyhoo, lots of ways to slice-n-dice this to make it easier to parse a SQL result set into something that can be used in a shell script.

---

The (obvious) general idea is to have the `select` query format your data in such a way to allow for (easier) parsing by the shell script.